# E0611 error on import when I know the file exists

Tags: pylint

With `pylint`, I'm getting an `E0611` error on an import when I know the file exists and the script runs fine. Suggestions?  I annotated the image below with the error.

[image]

Comment: strangely, I have the same problem when running `pylint` in the console, but only if I start it as `pylint *.py`. If I start `pylint any_specific_file.py`, it doesn't complain. And I don't use venv here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
In VS Code Preferences > Settings, change the "python.linting.pylintPath" to the virtual env path "/bin/pylint"
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/python/linting.md

Answer (score 0):

Removing all ignored files (in the `__pycache__`-folder, etc.) using the command `git clean -dfx` fixed the issue for me. (Warning: Ensure you do not have any important git-ignored files which you want to keep before executing this command.)